# How can I INSERT / UPDATE a tag value using EA API in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, computer-science, enterprise-architect

Is there any SDK/Method or API functionality that can update a specific {**Tagged Value Types**}  in my Enterprise Architect Project, using API-C# coding by using *Interop.EA.dll*

I did the following code but no effects on EA Tagged Value Types

```
    EA.TaggedValue MyTaggedVal= new TaggedValue();
    MyTaggedVal.Name = "XX";
    MyTaggedVal.Notes = "ZZ";
    MyTaggedVal.Value = "AZ";
    MyTaggedVal.SetAttribute("XX", "ZZ");
    MyTaggedVal.Update();
```

=======================================
an error, no results :( see the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create tagged values like that. You have to add it to an element.

```
EA.TaggedValue MyTaggedVal = MyElement.TaggedValues.AddNew("XX","");
```

Comment: I executed your code above, but it does not add the taggedValue to the exist element, 
--> Now If I want to Add new Tagged Value to EA Repository, but not to a particular element. how can i do that by C# code

Comment: You said in other comment that "You can use the undocumented and unsupported method Repository.Execute(SQLString)"
what is exactly the risk of using such methods?

Comment: @MikeBluer you have to call update() afterwards as well. Tagged values do not exist on their own, so you cannot create one like that

Comment: @MikeBluer You can easily destroy your repository with sql statements if you don't know exactly what you are doing. And if you use an unsupported method you can't go crying at Sparx support when things go south (pun intended)